# Getting an "Can't determine type for tag" on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Having trouble with this error. This error just started happening and I have no idea what is causing it. I have no accessed this project in a long time, but I remember it working perfecting prior to now.

> There are no additional tags and error persists after deleting final RelativeLayout tag.

```
Error: Can't determine type for tag '<RelativeLayout android:background="@color/backgroundcolorthree" android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="horizontal" tools:context=".ninegradesecondact" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


        <FrameLayout android:layout_below="@id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="30dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content">

                <Button android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:id="@+id/profilebutton" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/checklistbutton" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/checklistbutton" android:layout_width="100dp"/>

                <Button android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:id="@+id/upcomingtestsbutton" android:layout_below="@id/profilebutton" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_width="100dp" android:textSize="13dp"/>

                <Button android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:id="@+id/messagesbutton" android:layout_below="@id/profilebutton" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_toEndOf="@id/upcomingtestsbutton" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/upcomingtestsbutton" android:layout_width="100dp"/>

                <Button android:background="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:id="@+id/checklistbutton" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_marginStart="10dp" android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:layout_width="100dp"/>


            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark" android:id="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignTop="@id/grayoverlaytextview" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="125dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginRight="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="80dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/hometitletextview" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="16dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Home" android:textColor="@color/hometitlecolor" android:textSize="20sp" tools:text="Home"/>

        <TextView android:background="@color/accentcolorone" android:id="@+id/grayoverlaytextview" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="65dp" android:layout_margin="0dp" android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignRight="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignStart="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/nextsatacttextview" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="@id/nextsatacttextview">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/upcomingtestlabel" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentStart="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="0dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Upcoming Test:" android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:textSize="20sp"/>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_below="@id/upcomingtestlabel" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" android:layout_marginStart="20dp" android:layout_marginTop="20dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView android:id="@+id/nextsatacttext" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="SAT: 03/09" android:textColor="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" android:textSize="40sp"/>

                <RelativeLayout android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="30dp" android:layout_marginStart="30dp" android:layout_width="match_parent">
                    <Button android:background="@drawable/signup" android:id="@+id/satlinkbutton" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="100dp" android:visibility="visible"/>
                    <Button android:background="@drawable/signup" android:id="@+id/actlinkbutton" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="100dp" android:visibility="visible"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView ads:adSize="BANNER" ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111" android:id="@+id/adView" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"/>

    </RelativeLayout>'
```

Comment: Try to update dependencies in `app/build.gradle` to newest version.

Comment: `Can't determine type for tag` – Which tag? Does it indicate a particular line?

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is usually caused due to syntax issues. In your case there is one as well. There is an extra closing tag in the last line of your XML. Just remove `</RelativeLayout>'` from last line and the error will be gone.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Mike in comments, if there are any additional tags in your XML please update your question and share them all.

Comment: I think you missed the opening `<RelativeLayout>` tag at the very top. They have it butted up against the error message.

Comment: @MikeM.  I have tried deleting the last relative layout tag as well as adding one to the beginning. The error still persists. Any ideas? There are no additional tags in the XML.

Comment: @KerrickCavanaugh I wasn't suggesting to delete that tag. I can see that you have them all matched. I was just letting Jordan know that the `</RelativeLayout>` at the end wasn't extra.

Comment: If there aren't any additional tags then the last </RelativeLayout> tag is definitely additional (unless you consider the error line a tag).

Comment: @KerrickCavanaugh please edit your question and add XML and error to seperate sections for avoiding any confusion.

Comment: That's what I meant by "They have it butted up against the error message." That's the opening tag in the XML. It's not part of the error message.

Comment: @MikeM. In that case, the error message might not be complete as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue. In my case there was a mismatch between gradle version and AGP dependency. Just run the AGP Upgrade Assistant from Tools menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check file location. I had `AndroidManifest.xml` misplaced in `res/values` instead of root. Layouts have also special folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this (it worked for me. I was having this error on a boilerplate "Hello World" My Application right out of the box before modifying it).
https://www.google.com/search?q=Can%27t+determine+type+for+tag+%27%3Cmacro+name%3D%22m3_comp_bottom_app_bar_container_color%22%3E%3Fattr%2FshapeAppearance+Corner+mall&rlz=1C1SQJL_enUS783US783&oq=c&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j69i60l4j69i65l2.5223j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:4fe0d9cc,vid:Zlkj1COxKcM